# Force QtQuick Controls Button type to be checked onPress

Tags: qt, qml

There is an incredibly frustrating behavior that occurs with the QtQuick Controls Button type. The checked property does not switch to true when the mouse button is pressed. It only switches to true once the mouse button has been released. This creates a situation where, if you have the button's background color bound to the checked property and you want the background color to change (both ways, on / off) onPressed rather than onClicked, you are unable to do that without writing some really weird code. Code that feels unnatural, like you are fighting the button type's implementation. For example, in the following code:

```
Button {
        id: my_button
        width: 200
        height: 200
        text: "Cool Button"
        checkable: true
        hoverEnabled: true
        background: Rectangle {
            color:  my_button.checked ? "orange" : "blue"
        }
    }
```

the button will only switch to orange and back to blue when the mouse button is released. If you add a pressed check to the color binding like this:

```
color:  my_button.pressed || my_button.checked ? "orange" : "blue"
```

it will switch to orange onPressed but won't switch back to blue until onClicked (mouse button is released). Is there any way to force the checked property to be toggled onPressed instead on onClicked? Thanks.

**Update:**

I got it to work using the following binding:

```
color:  {
      if(my_button.pressed && my_button.checked){
          return "blue"
      }
      else if(my_button.pressed && !my_button.checked){
          return "orange"
      }
      else if(!my_button.pressed && my_button.checked) {
          return "orange"
      }
      else if(!my_button.pressed && !my_button.checked) {
          return "blue"
      }
}
```

Although it is quite verbose.

Comment: @eyllanesc Almost, but the return to blue only happens on mouse button release.

Comment: try with: `color: my_button.pressed == my_button.checked ? "orange" : "blue"`

Comment: That is a simplification of the code that you have added that can be summarized: if pressed and checked are the same (both true or both false) then it returns "blue" otherwise it returns "orange"

Comment: or  `color: (my_button.pressed || my_button.checked) ? "blue" : "orange"`

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a totally normal behavior for a button. As long as the user didn't executed a complete click on a button it won't change to checked. Imagine a scenario in which the user presses the button and then releases outside. In this case the "click" (or the activation of the button) was cancelled.

The way of solving your background color issue without using a "weird" binding is by using [States](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-state.html):

```
Button {
    id: myButton
    width: 200
    height: 200
    text: "Cool Button"
    checkable: true
    hoverEnabled: true
    background: Rectangle {
        id: background
        color: "blue"
        states: [
            State {
                name: "PressedAndChecked"
                when: myButton.pressed && myButton.checked
                PropertyChanges { target: background; color: "blue" }
            },
            State {
                name: "PressedAndNotChecked"
                when: myButton.pressed && !myButton.checked
                PropertyChanges { target: background; color: "orange" }
            },
            State {
                name: "NotPressedAndChecked"
                when: !myButton.pressed && myButton.checked
                PropertyChanges { target: background; color: "orange" }
            },
            State {
                name: "NotPressedAndNotChecked"
                when: !myButton.pressed && !myButton.checked
                PropertyChanges { target: background; color: "blue" }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also implement the behavior with only two states by combining the states with similar color values. This could be achieved by concatenating their when statements with ||. It would decrease readability though.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like `myButton.pressed === myButton.checked` would work for the blue condition and `!==` for the orange condition.